# Laravel elFinder Image upload issue

Tags: php, laravel

I used [this package](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-elfinder) on my app to upload images and files, in local it worked just fine but since i moved my app to server i'm getting this error:

> Call to a member function hasPermissionTo() on null
>   in AdminMiddleware.php (line 22)

**I'm using TinyMCE 4 with Laravel 5.4**

Here is my `AdminMiddleware`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\User;

class AdminMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      $user = User::all()->count();
      if (!($user == 1)) {
          if (!Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo('Administer roles & permissions')) //If user does //not have this permission
      {
              abort('401');
          }
      }

      return $next($request);
    }
}
```

and here is my script on `post create page`

```
@section('scripts')
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/select2.min.js')}}"></script>
<script>
  var editor_config = {
    path_absolute : "/",
    selector: "textarea.my-editor",
    plugins: [
      "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
      "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
      "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
      "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern codesample"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image media | emoticons charmap | code codesample | forecolor backcolor",
    relative_urls: false,
    remove_script_host: false,
    file_browser_callback : function(field_name, url, type, win) {
      var x = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;
      var y = window.innerHeight|| document.documentElement.clientHeight|| document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;

      var cmsURL = editor_config.path_absolute + 'laravel-filemanager?field_name=' + field_name;
      if (type == 'image') {
        cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Images";
      } else {
        cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Files";
      }

      tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
        file: '<?= route('elfinder.tinymce4') ?>',// use an absolute path!
        title: 'File Manager',
        width: 900,
        height: 450,
        resizable: 'yes'
      }, {
        setUrl: function (url) {
          win.document.getElementById(field_name).value = url;
        }
      });
    }
  };

  tinymce.init(editor_config);
</script>
<script>
  {!! \File::get(base_path('vendor/barryvdh/laravel-elfinder/resources/assets/js/standalonepopup.js')) !!}
</script>
@endsection
```

Does anyone know why I have this issue and how to fix it?

[image: error image]

Comment: any idea......?

Comment: I got the same error. Have you resolved it?

Comment: Not yet unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

I uploaded view files in package folder in `public_html`

and also elfinder middelware changed to array like:

`'middleware' => array('web', 'Auth'),`

now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Auth::user()` and there aren't any user logged in, you are calling a method on a null object so before you have to check if the user is already logged in. You can fix it by using the `Auth::check()` method right before.

Quick example:

```
if(Auth::check()){
  //we have an user logged, let's check their permissions
  if (!Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo('Administer roles & permissions')) {

  }
}else{
        // there aren't any user logged in
}
```

Comment: This i use for post creating and route of that is secured by middleware admin, so obviously till I'm not logged in and I'm not an admin i cannot see that page to wanna upload image, I don't think this be the issue.

Comment: I would need to see the full error stack trace then, but this kind of errors use to be solved like this

Comment: Full error is the image i sent in my question. I use this package to upload image inside my posts.

Comment: Did you update your .env after change server? Try it under private navigation too

Comment: you mean change from local to production? if that, yes i did website is online now just this part not working.